# Nginx не отдает статику

Tags: linux, nginx, веб-сервер

Доброго времени. 
Есть конфиг

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {

    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # pagespeed On;
    # pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx/";
    # pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/";
    # pagespeed FileCachePath "/var/cache/ngx111/";

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    proxy_cache_path /home/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=all:32m max_size=1g;
    sendfile off; 

    keepalive_timeout 65;


    # optimization
     gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_buffers 32 4k;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript text/xml text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;


    server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sitename_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myKey.key;

        location ~* ^.+\.(js|css)$ {
            expires max;
        }

        listen 443;
        server_name www.sitename.com;

        return 301 https://sitename.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/sitename_com.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myKey.key;

        location ~* ^.+\.(js|css)$ {
            expires max;
        }

        listen 443;
        server_name sitename.com;

        charset utf8;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            charset utf-8;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_pass http://unix:/home/lex/myproject/second.sock;

        }
         location /assets {
             autoindex on;
             alias /home/rast/src/assets;

         }
        location /calc {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;

        }

        location /calc2 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


        location = /favicon.ico {
            alias /home/rast/src/favicon.ico;
            access_log off; log_not_found off;
        }

        location = /sitemap.xml {

            alias /home/rast/src/sitemap.xml;
        }
        location = /robot.txt {

            alias /home/rast/src/robots.txt;
        }
        location = /robots.txt {

            alias /home/rast/src/robots.txt;
        }
        location /static/ {

            # optimization
            etag on;
            charset utf-8;
            expires max;
            sendfile on;
            # sendfile off;
            # autoindex on;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            # root /home/rast/src/;
            alias /home/rast/src/static/;
        }



        location /media/ {

            etag on;
            charset utf-8;
            expires max;
            sendfile off;
            #autoindex on
            root /home/rast/src/;
        }

        location /wp-content/ {
            etag on;
            expires max;
            sendfile off;
            charset utf-8;
            #autoindex on
            root /home/rast/src/;
        }

        location = /static/logo.svg {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/logo.svg;
        }

        location = /static/logotype.png {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/logotype.png;
        }

        location = /static/admin/css/dashboard.css {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/admin/css/dashboard.css;
        }

        location = /static/js/slick.min.js {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/js/slick.min.js;
        }
        #china
        location = /static/china/css/style.css {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/china/css/style.css;
        }

        location = /static/china/js/jquery.min.js {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/china/js/jquery.min.js;
        }

        location = /static/china/js/html5.js {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/china/js/html5.js;
        }

        location = /static/china/js/main.js {
            alias /home/rast/src/static/china/js/main.js;
        }



    }


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name www.sitename.com;
        return 301 https://sitename.com$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Проблема в том что статические папки assets,static не работают. 
Подскажите,второй день не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: В чем выражается «неработоспособность»? Какие проявления этого, ошибки в логах, etc?

Comment: ошибки нет, просто опечатка. 
Вопрос закрываю